# Arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy un poco desorientado a la hora de buscar valores que yo quiero en un array bidimesional en java Script. Intento buscar el/los Alumnos que hayan aprobado todo. Haber si me podéis echar una mano. Gracias.
Este es el c´digo principal

```
var alumnos = ["Juan", "Pepe", "Alba", "Maria", "Alvaro", "Roberto", "Laura", "Daniel", "Cristina", "David"];
var asignaturas = ["Matemáticas", "Lengua", "Inglés", "Física", "Música"];
//Mostrar la tabla con las notas
function generaAleatorio(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

}

var notas = new Array(asignaturas.length + 1);
notas[0] = new Array();
notas[0].push("X");
for (var i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
    notas[0].push(alumnos[i]);
}

for (var i = 1; i < notas.length; i++) {
    notas[i] = new Array(alumnos.length + 1);
    notas[i][0] = asignaturas[i - 1];
}

for (var i = 1; i < notas.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < notas[i].length; j++) {
        notas[i][j] = generaAleatorio(0, 10);

    }
}

//Mostrar aquellos alumnos que han aprobado todo.
function todoAprobado(){
    for (var i = 1; i < notas.length; i++) {
        console.log("Modulo" + notas[i][0]);
        for (var j = 1; j < notas[i].length; j++) {
            if (notas[i][j] >= 5) {
                console.log("Alumno " + notas[0][j] + " " + notas[i][j]);
            } else {
                console.log("Ningún alumno ha aprobado todas las asignturas");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Es algún ejercicio que te han propuesto o es de tu propia cosecha? Tal y como lo veo yo me parece que es muy enrevesado el modo en el que lo estás haciendo. Sería muchísimo más sencillo si tuvieras un array de objetos, cada uno con una propiedad para el alumno y otra con un array de asignaturas (o de notas)

Comment: Es de un ejercicio que me han puesto.....

Comment: ¿Y en el ejercicio que te han puesto, te piden usar únicamente `array's`? Porque como @Kiko_L comenta, sería mucho más sencillo usar objetos. Saludos

Comment: Si array, este primer ejercicio, debe ser con arrays